# How to re-render re-frame's as-element in ClojureScript?

Tags: clojure, clojurescript, reagent, re-frame

I have this code block when `:link-flows` sub has changed, `@(subscribe [:link-flows ::assign-to-flow-q])` is not triggered and re-render does not run.

I think it's `re-frame/as-element` fn?

Also wrapping into `(fn [])` throws an error due to React child table error so it's not an option.

`Functions are not valid as a React child. This may happen if you return a Component instead of <Component /> from render. Or maybe you meant to call this function rather than return it.`

```clj
(let [flows @(subscribe [:link-flows ::assign-to-flow-q])]
  (re-frame/as-element
    [ant/select
     {:showSearch       true
      :optionFilterProp "children"
      :onSearch         #(dispatch [:set-ns-search-q ::assign-to-flow-q %])}
     (map (fn [flow]
            [ant/select-option
             {:value (:id flow)} (:name flow)])
          flows)]))
```

Is there any way to make this re-render mechanism work?

Answer (score 0):

In this code, the render function is not clear. For re-render to happen, the subscription should be inside the render function. I would still suggest to wrap it inside a `(fn [])` and remove the `(re-frame/as-element)`.

Comment: re-frame/as-element is a must, I'm using Ant Design lib so I need to use as-element.

Comment: Ok, you are passing this to another component. In that case i would suggest use `as-element` on top of this function. Say you define `(defn my-fun [] ...)` and then use `(re-frame/as-element [my-fun])` in place of the above code.